# what about a mem leak in a child process

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, fork, parent-child

Im on unix platform.

The memory of a process with a memleak is cleaned at process termination.

What about a process, that has spawned a child, where the child has a memleak.
Will the leaked memory be cleaned up at childprocess termination? Or will this memory now stick with the parent process.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The memory allocated by the child process exists only in the child process's virtual address space, not the parent's. It will be freed as soon as the child process terminates or replaces itself with a new program image via one of the `exec` family of functions.

This is in contrast to threads, which share a common virtual address space, and where allocations made in a new thread will persist after the thread exits and remain usable by other threads.

Comment: +1 though you should mention the fact that some calls like `vfork` and `clone` result in a shared address space.

Comment: I wouldn't call the results of `vfork` a shared memory space. `vfork` has undefined behavior if you call anything but a short list of safe functions between the `vfork` and `_exit` or one of the `exec` family of functions. Certainly calling `malloc` from the `vfork`'d child is likely to lead to memory corruption. The same generally applies to `clone` with a shared address space, unless you're the implementor of the system threads implementation and have the liberty to add the right synchronization mechanisms into the system `malloc` implementation.

Comment: And to highlight the undefined behavior, it's completely allowed (by the most recent specs that had `vfork`, IIRC; the current POSIX does not even have `vfork`) for `vfork` to simply call `fork`, so you can't rely on having a shared memory space after `vfork`.